# Using conditional formatting on Excel slicers

Tags: excel, pivot-table, conditional-formatting, slicers

I have intermediate excel skills and am relatively new to pivot charts and slicers.  I have made a pivot chart out of production-related data.  Next to the chart is a slicer that displays all the different products in production.  Basically, whenever the user clicks on one of the products in the slicer, it displays a bar graph mixed with a line graph.  If the bars are exceeding the line, then the product is considered "critical" (it is exceeding production capacity).  I want to use conditional formatting (or another method, preferably not a macro) to highlight the products on the slicer in red that are critical.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You want to conditional format the chart right not the slicer?

Comment: No, I want to conditional format the slicer.  To make the slicer options appear in red if they are critical.

Comment: You may find something of use here http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/getting-fancy-with-your-excel-slicers/  It is not something I have ever done bar custom format for company colours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't conditionally format Slicer Items. Instead, your best bet is to use a second PivotTable that only shows the critical products in it.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up adding whether it was critical or not in the original data table, and then added an additional slicer showing critical vs non critical products.